# ASP.NET PasswordRecovery control doesn't provide functionality to save previous password after password reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, password-recovery

i use `<asp:PasswordRecovery>` control to reset the password of the user and send to his email a new auto-generated password. The problem is that when a user sends the username via this control, the password is automatically changed in the database to the generated one. I don't like this behavior, because any site visitor can change somebodies password using my PasswordRecovery page. I want the database to remember both old and new(generated) passwords until the first login after password recovery process. Strange that `<asp:PasswordRecovery>` control doesn't provide this functionality.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only option is going to be to roll your own.

My recommended approach would be the following:

1. allow your user to input their email address
2. send them an email with the option to reset their password with a provided link
3. once they click the link, change the password then send them an email containing their new password, or a link that allows them to set their new password